# Command line arguments for headless Chrome perfromance

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm using headless Chrome (via Ferrum) and I am wondering if I can increase the performance of the (relatively intensive) Chrome processes by passing additional command line flags. There are [quite a lot of options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/), and not a lot of information of optimizing headless chrome, though [there is some helpful official insight about this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher/blob/master/docs/chrome-flags-for-tools.md). I'm wondering if there are more in depth tweaks for optimizing headless performance, such as disabling or limiting the the rendering engine more than already is done by default.